# Ruby keyword arguments syntax explanation

Tags: ruby, hash, syntactic-sugar, keyword-argument

If we have a `create_widget` method defined this way:

```
def create_widget(size, properties)
  puts properties.class #=> Hash
  puts properties[:id] #=> table22
end
```

What is the difference between:

```
create_widget(6, {:id => "table22", :class => "Cart"})
create_widget(6, :id => "table22", :class => "Cart")
create_widget(6, id: "table22", class: "Cart")
```

In any cases, the second argument is a `Hash`, and renders the same result.

Comment: They're all interpreted the same way with just variations of syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All three of your lines are functionally identical.

Hash objects are declared using the curly braces `{}`, and Ruby started out pairing keys and values with the rocket `=>`. So declaring one as you pass it to a function would look like your first line.

```
create_widget(6, {:id => "table22", :class => "Cart"})
```

For convenience and clean syntax, Ruby lets you omit `{}` if the Hash is the last argument, which gets you line 2. This is the common idiom for lots of methods that accept some kind of extra options hash:

```
def create_widget(number, properties = {}); end
create_widget(6, :id => "table22", :class => "Cart")
```

Ruby 1.9 introduced the colon `:` syntax to replace the rocket `=>` **when your keys are symbols**, leading to line 3:

```
create_widget(6, id: "table22", class: "Cart")
```

So in these cases, the differences are purely visual. Note though that if you have non-symbol keys, you need to use rocket `=>` syntax. You're welcome to mix them together in the same hash:

```
create_widget(6, "id" => "table22", class: "Cart")
```

---

Also of note, Ruby 2 introduced keyword arguments, which look identical to line 3. Keyword arguments give you ordering flexibility in addition to the descriptive names people were getting out of option hashes. They also let you set defaults more easily than option hashes, so `create_widget` could look like this:

```
def create_widget(number, id:, class: "Cart")
```

`id:` declares that we've named an argument `id`, and it has no default so it is required. `class: "Cart"`, on the other hand, will default to `"Cart"`, so is optional. Now all of these calls behave the same:

```
create_widget(6, id: "table22")
create_widget(6, id: "table22", class: "Cart")
create_widget(6, class: "Cart", id: "table22")
```